# Tools or techniques for autofilling Web forms for testing purposes?

Tags: php, html, webforms

At work, we create a lot of multi-page Web forms, that are sometimes 7-10 pages long. (Think online school applications or something similar.) To test the forms, I need to fill out each form as if I were a user--so for example, I'll enter "firstname" in the field labeled "First Name". This way, I can verify that the form fields are matching up to the correct fields in our database.

I'm looking for suggestions for ways to automate this process as much as possible. I'm sure it can't be completely automated, but anything that would help reduce the time it takes to enter in contact and address information over and over again. At least one good approach (I think) would be to have a script run that goes through each form field, reads the label, and then enters appropriate text in the corresponding form field. So when it finds a text box labeled "Street Address", it enters the text "streetaddress" in that field.

Obviously some fields will have some validation on them, so my script/program should be able to either skip those and notify my that they need to be entered manually, or just enter information that is valid for that field.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I know that there are plenty of Web testing tools out there, like Selenium, but I don't know which, if any, can do this kind of testing.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at selenium or watir. They can automate your testing by filling out form fields against thier internal database among other things.

Quick test is another paid solution for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help. From what I can tell, Selenium (and I think iMacros too) can *record* what I do and play it back any number of times. But I don't want something to record the form input, because it will only be done a couple of times anyway. (Actually, I do want that, but it's not mainly what I want.) I'm looking for something that will automatically fill in the fields without my having to type them in initially. It will just go through each form field and enter text based on the field's label. Can Selenium do that, AFAYK?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the imacros plugin for firefox.  I think they have plugins for other browsers too.  Its free and dead simple to use.  You can record a session, and replay it.  Edit the macros in a text file, and even do some light scripting (in their language, as well as javascript).